# Выбор файлообменника

Tags: файлы, веб-программирование

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, удобный и безопасный **файлообменник** для хранения файлов сайта. **Главное** - это простота, удобство и большой срок хранения файлов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужно хранить где-то данные, можно пользоваться

- Amazon Simple Storage Service
- What is Google Cloud Storage

И то, и другое - удобно, безопасно и надежно, но стоит некоторых денег.

Есть менее известные опции:

- File-Works
- Leap-File
- ShugarSync
- Dropbox

Answer (score 1):

Облака типа Mail.ru, Яндекс-диска, Google drive, dropbox'a. Там файлы хранятся вечно.

Comment: Пожалуйста, не надо заниматься некрофилией, да еще на сомнительных вопросах.

Comment: @KromStern, не надо кидать старые "сомнительные" вопросы в очередь - вдруг кому-то захочется на них ответить ;) На мой взгляд, этот вопрос нормальный и закрывать его не надо.

Comment: А лучше не ответить, а привести в порядок (хотя этот впору удалить). В настоящей форме это типичный вопрос-опросник, субъективный и без однозначного ответа.

Comment: @Qwertiy ваш ответ под стать вопросу - ужасен -.-

Comment: @KromStern, для файлообменника критерии удобства вполне очевидны. В принципе, я могу дополнить ими вопрос, но не вижу в этом смысла, ибо очевидно. Плюс там прописан критерий в виде срока хранения. Вроде бы всё объективно?

Comment: @Qwertiy если очевидно, то зачем вообще ваш ответ, который, по сути, ничем не отличается от ответа Nicolas'а. Я предполагаю, что если уже есть принятый ответ, то писать новый имеет смысл только если он намного подробнее.

Comment: @Suvitruf, за 3 года что-то могло и поменяться. И у меня вроде пересечение с тем ответом только по дропбокусу и, возможно, гуглу.

Comment: @Qwertiy так раз, по вашим словам, они ничем не отличаются, тогда ответ Nicolos'а включает весь ваш ответ)

Comment: @Suvitruf, критерии не отличаются. А набор сервисов я назвал другой. А про 3 сервиса из того ответа я вообще впервые слышу, так что не могу сказать, устарела информация или нет.